# Display different content in the modal using flask

Tags: flask, modal-dialog

I want to create a function using flask. On the page there are multiple buttons. When I click a button, the modal will display different contents depending on what button is clicked.
Currently I write a button and a modal inside the for loop, but it will generate lots of html. I wonder if there is a better way to do so

Here is the code

```
{% for temp_value in id_list  %}
    <!-- Button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal" id="btnUpdate"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateModalLabel">Data</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                    {% data_list[temp_value] %} <!-- show data -->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnConfirm" onclick="form_submit()">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks